# c# visual studio - Better tool to use with formatted text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, controls, richtextbox, formatted-text

I'm looking for a tool to replace richtextbox with.

Is there anything that I could use which makes it easier to format text entered at runtime?

(I.E: I'd like to change the text color/style of the text the user writes in the control.)

Edit:

I want to be able to easily change the color/font/style/size of any string or part of a string with out having to dabble in too much rtf coding.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for, as RichTextBox allows setting text color (etc) just fine. Are you looking for more advanced formatting functionality, as offered by paid components like http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Rich_Editor/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out AvalonEdit from SharpDevelop project. It has declarative formatting with 'out-of-the-box' support for many languages. And it can control any formatting by code as well.

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

And it's even available in NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/AvalonEdit